# R: Cannot update packages on MacOsX

Tags: r, macos

When I try to update `R` packages on Mac OS X (as an ordinary user with admin privileges, i.e., `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources` is writable to me), I get this:

```
> update.packages(instlib = .libPaths()[1], checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
Warning: package 'foreign' in library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'lattice' in library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'Matrix' in library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'mgcv' in library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library' will not be updated
Warning: package 'plotrix' in library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library' will not be updated
trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/Hmisc_3.13-0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1514975 bytes (1.4 Mb)
opened URL
==============================================
downloaded 1.3 Mb

trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/Matrix_1.1-1.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3450203 bytes (3.3 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 3.3 Mb

trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/nleqslv_2.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 89297 bytes (87 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 87 Kb

trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/plotrix_3.5-2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 624295 bytes (609 Kb)
opened URL
========
downloaded 108 Kb

trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/nlme_3.1-113.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2132159 bytes (2.0 Mb)
opened URL
==========
downloaded 457 Kb

trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/rpart_4.1-4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 890223 bytes (869 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 869 Kb

Hmisc/help/Hmisc.rdb: (Empty error message)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
plotrix/R/plotrix.rdb: (Empty error message)
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Error: file ‘/var/tmp/RtmpY8MhsZ/downloaded_packages/plotrix_3.5-2.tgz’ is not an OS X binary package
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 1402861 != reported length 1514975
Calls: update.packages -> install.packages -> .install.macbinary -> download.packages -> try -> tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> doTryCatch -> download.file
2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 111247 != reported length 624295
Calls: update.packages -> install.packages -> .install.macbinary -> download.packages -> try -> tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> doTryCatch -> download.file
3: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 468901 != reported length 2132159
Calls: update.packages -> install.packages -> .install.macbinary -> download.packages -> try -> tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> doTryCatch -> download.file
4: 'tar' returned non-zero exit code 1 
5: 'tar' returned non-zero exit code 1 
Execution halted
```

The `.tgz` files in `/var/tmp/RtmpY8MhsZ/downloaded_packages/` are valid tar/gzip files:

```
$ tar tvfz /var/tmp/RtmpY8MhsZ/downloaded_packages/Matrix_1.1-1.1.tgz 
drwxrwxr-x  0 root   admin       0 Jan  1 01:47 Matrix/
-rw-rw-r--  0 root   admin    2433 Jan  1 01:45 Matrix/Copyrights
drwxrwxr-x  0 root   admin       0 Jan  1 01:45 Matrix/data/
-rw-rw-r--  0 root   admin    1253 Jan  1 01:45 Matrix/DESCRIPTION
drwxrwxr-x  0 root   admin       0 Jan  1 01:47 Matrix/doc/
-rw-rw-r--  0 root   admin   72521 Jan  1 01:45 Matrix/Doxyfile
drwxrwxr-x  0 root   admin       0 Jan  1 01:45 Matrix/external/
drwxrwxr-x  0 root   admin       0 Jan  1 01:47 Matrix/help/
drwxrwxr-x  0 root   admin       0 Jan  1 01:47 Matrix/html/
drwxrwxr-x  0 root   admin       0 Jan  1 01:45 Matrix/include/
.....
```

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you running R as root?

Comment: @hd1: no, ordinary user with admin privileges; see edit.

Comment: The warning may simply mean you already have the latest version of those packages.  Try `library(lattice)` then `sessionInfo()` to see what version it loaded, then compare to what's available on CRAN.

Comment: @BryanHanson: this is an _error_, not a _warning_.

Comment: See this messag ein the R-SIG-Mac mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2013-November/010569.html

Comment: The first 5 lines are warnings.  Just thought it would be worth investigating as in my experience the early warnings and errors cascade out and cause much of what typically follows.  Have you tried `install.packages` instead of `update.packages`?  Re-install `R`?  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [recommended by @Bhas](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2013-November/010569.html), the solution is to set the `TAR` environment variable:

```
TAR=/usr/bin/tar R CMD ...
```